# C graph adjacency list implementation growing neighbour array

Tags: c, graph, adjacency-list

I found an implementation and was going throught the code and one part seems unclear to me.

```
struct graph {
    int n;              /* number of vertices */
    int m;              /* number of edges */
    struct successors {
        int d;          /* number of successors */
        int len;        /* number of slots in array */
        char is_sorted; /* true if list is already sorted */
        int list[1];    /* actual list of successors */
    } *alist[1];
};
```

in the graph_add_edge function

```
/* do we need to grow the list? */
while (g->alist[u]->d >= g->alist[u]->len) {
    g->alist[u]->len *= 2;
    g->alist[u] =
        realloc(g->alist[u],
            sizeof(struct successors) + sizeof(int) * (g->alist[u]->len - 1));
}
```

why does the length have to be doubled? why is it even needed? isn't it always d+1 (number of successors + 1) to make room for the next item?

[Full code](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/C%282f%29Graphs.html)

Comment: Because it's less costly in terms of CPU time to double the size each time you need more memory instead of adding just 1 to the size. In the latter case `realloc` will be called for each newly added edge, and `realloc` is pretty expensive. Imagine you have 100 edges: realloc will be called 100 times, but if you double the size it will only be called log2(100) times.

Comment: @MichaelWalz could You please Your comment to answer section to be accepted?

Comment: @Kamiccolo done, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's less costly in terms of CPU time to double the size each time you need more memory instead of adding just 1 to the size.

In the latter case `realloc` will be called for each newly added edge, and `realloc` is pretty expensive. Imagine you have 128 edges: `realloc` will be called 128 times, but if you double the size each time, it will only be called 7 `= log2(128)` times.

Furthermore `realloc` will most likely be slower the longer the original memory portion is, because `realloc` will potentially copy the old memory portion buffer to a new larger one, and the longer the portion, the longer the copying will take.